# Output non-undefined type when input type is defined

Tags: typescript, undefined, typescript-generics

I just wrote this function:

```
const cloneUrl = <T extends (URL | undefined)>(url: T): T => url instanceof URL
  ? new URL(url.toString())
  : undefined;
```

However, this has errors (or at least, errors very close to this):

> 'URL | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'URL | undefined'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'undefined' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'URL | undefined'.

Clearly I am not grasping something fundamental about TypeScript...

My goal is to make it so that when `cloneUrl` is called with a type known to be a URL, the return type is URL, but when `cloneUrl` is called with a type that is `URL | undefined`, the return type is `URL | undefined`.

Example:

```
class UrlWrapper {
  private readonly _urlOne: URL
  private readonly _urlTwo?: URL

  constructor(urlOne: URL, urlTwo?: URL) {
    this._urlOne = urlOne;
    this._urlTwo = urlTwo;
  }

  get urlOne(): URL { return cloneUrl(this._urlOne); }
  get urlTwo(): URL | undefined { return cloneUrl(this._urlTwo); }
}
```

See how `urlWrapper.urlOne` should always be a non-undefinable value, but `urlTwo` can be?

I have tried different type constraints:

- `<T extends URL>`
- `<T extends URL ? URL : undefined>`

I have tried different parameters:

- `url?: T`
- `url: T | undefined`

I've tried casting the results:

- `undefined as undefined`
- `undefined as T | undefined`

I've tried making the private field optional, or changing its type.

I've tried using a type checker function:

- `const checkIsUrl = (url: unknown): url is URL => url instanceof URL;`

...and many more.

But there is something about how TypeScript thinks about types that I don't have the right mental model for, so I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with this recently and found the following seems to work using generics with a [conditional return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html). There's the ugliness of the `any` use, but I'm not sure how to avoid that. It's voodoo I don't fully grok, but the types are inferred to what you expect.

```
export function cloneUrl<T extends URL | undefined>(value: T): T extends URL ? URL : undefined {
    return value instanceof URL ? new URL(value.toString()) : (undefined as any);
}

let source: URL | undefined = new URL("test");
cloneUrl(source); // URL
source = undefined;
cloneUrl(source); // undefined
let optionalSource: URL | undefined;
cloneUrl(optionalSource); // URL or undefined
cloneUrl(new Date()); // Nope: Date isn't a URL
```

Comment: There's no type constraint on `T`, though, to avoid passing in other objects, such as `cloneUrl(new Date())`...

Comment: Yes, fair point. That would be important :). I did this for cloning arbitrary value and that fit...

Comment: I think adding `extends URL` to type parameter does the job. See update?

Comment: This "works" in that it causes no compile-time errors, but it won't work at runtime because when given an optional value (`extends URL | undefined`) the result type is `URL`, not `URL | undefined`. Using the example class I gave, property `urlTwo` can be given an explicit return type of `URL` which is incorrect.

Comment: That is, `get urlTwo(): URL { return cloneUrl(this._urlTwo); }` should be an error, but isn't.

Comment: Good catch. Updated again, seems to handle the optional case now?

Comment: That seems to have done it. Can you offer some thoughts on how to think about this problem in the future so that I can get to a working solution faster? I tried so many different things, and it's a little confusing why this works and other techniques don't. For example, it seems like `<T extends URL>` should work, because that still allows `undefined` to be passed in, but then other errors occur. It's also very strange to convert `undefined` to `any`—that would not be something I would have tried, at *all*. Some conceptual help here would actually be more useful than solving this specifically.

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately I'm still at trial-and-error/cargo-cult mode when it comes to advanced types. I suspect the 'undefined as any' hack may be a bug since it certainly isn't intuitive.  Regarding the extends needing undefined, I think it has to do with the "distributive conditional types" discussed in the link.